What is the way to chain methods with different signatures describing a business process?
I have the following process I'd like to describe with chained methods returning Either.
The process receives a context object containing a WhateverInput and correlationId and processes these in the following steps:

validation of the WhateverInput
mapping the WhateverInput to WhateverEntity
saving the WhateverEntity in a storage
mapping the returned WhateverEntity (having Id at this point) to WhateverResult

The correlationId is there to mark which process the operation belongs to if the process fails.
What I tried is map and flatMap, but both of them expects a function where the input is the Either's Right and an Either as a return value. However my method signatures look like below due to that I don't want to put the correlation id into a field.

public class VavrPractice {

    public static void handle(Context context) {

        var result = Either.right(context)
            .map(validateInput(context.getWhateverEntityInput(), context.getCorrelationId())) // shows error
    }

    private static Either<ErrorResult, WhateverEntityInput> validateInput(WhateverEntityInput whateverEntityInput, UUID correlationId) {}

    private static Either<ErrorResult, WhateverEntity> mapToWhateverEntity(WhateverEntityInput whateverEntityInput, UUID correlationId) {}

    private static Either<ErrorResult, WhateverEntity> saveToDatabase(WhateverEntityInput whateverEntityInput, UUID correlationId) {}

    private static Either<ErrorResult, WhateverEntityResult> mapToWhateverEntityResult(WhateverEntity whateverEntity, UUID correlationId) {}
}

How to do this in a nice, best/good practices way? What I can think of is creating a Context object adding to it both the WhateverInput and correlationId and this Context will be the Right side of the Either and moving this object between methods. But, it feels a bit clunky, heavy.
I study functional programming in both Java and C# in the same time and the example above can be done in C# using Bind and I am looking for an equivalent for that or the solution how the Bind, what it seems like map or flatMap, can be done.
FYI, this exact question is asked in the vavr repo on GitHub.

Why are all of your methods static? Statics methods will make your code tightly coupled & early bound making testing difficult among other things

Why your WhateverEntityInput accept WhateverEntityInput as parameter? Should it be  WhateverEntity?

As for static, this is the first thing I read in the books. These methods are static and I followed what I read. As I mentioned I am new in the functional world.

Why I received a minus vote? What is the problem with the question?

@talex do you refer to the validateInput method?

@AndrasCsanyi sorry. Pasted wrong string. I'm reffering to saveToDatabase method. In my answer I made it accept WhateverEntity instead of WhateverEntityInput.

@talex ehh, that is a typo at my side.

If you fix your types a little you can do
    public static void handle(ContextX context) {
        UUID correlationId = context.getCorrelationId();
        var result = Either.<ErrorResult, WhateverEntityInput>right(context.getWhateverEntityInput())
            .flatMap(i -> validateInput(i, correlationId))
            .flatMap(i -> mapToWhateverEntity(i, correlationId))
            .flatMap(e -> saveToDatabase(e, correlationId))
            .flatMap(e -> mapToWhateverEntityResult(e, correlationId));
    }


I see now what I did wrong, thanks for the help.

Have you considered using Result instead of Either?
public class Result<T> {
   private final boolean success;
   private T value;             // only populated when success = true
   private List<String> errors; // only populated when success = false

   private Result<T>(boolean success, T value, List<String> errors) {
      this.success = success;
      this.value = value;
      this.errors = errors;
   }

   public static <T> Result<T> success(T value) {
      return new Result<>(true, value, null);
   }

   public static <T> Result<T> error(List<String> errors) {
      return new Result<>(false, null, errors);
   }

   public static <T> Result<T> error(String error) {
      return new Result<>(false, null, List.of(error));
   }

   public <T2> Result<T2> map(Function<T, T2> mapper) {
      return success ? Result.success(mapper.apply(value)) : this;
   }

   public T orElse(T errValue) {
      return success ? value : errValue;
   }

   public boolean isSuccess() {
      return success;
   }

   public boolean isError() {
      return !success;
   }

   public T getValue() {
      if (!success) throw new IllegalStateException();
      return value;
   }

   public List<String> getErrors() {
      if (success) throw new IllegalStateException();
      return errors;
   }
}

public class MyClass {
   public String doLotsOfStuff() {
      String value = "v1";

      Result<String> result = doStuff1(value)
          .map(this::doStuff2)
          .map(this::doStuff3);

      if (result.isError()) {
          System.err.println(result.getErrors().toString());
      }
      return result.orElse("error");
   }

   private Result<String> doStuff1(String inValue) { 
      if (!inValue.startsWith("foo")) {
         return Result.error("inValue does not start with 'foo'");
      }
      return Result.success("bar");
   }
   private Result<String> doStuff2(String inValue) { ... }
   private Result<String> doStuff3(String inValue) { ... }
}


There is no such type in vavr, at least after searching for it for 5 mins I haven't found it.

Ah, sorry... didn't see the "vavr" tag. Assumed plain old vanilla java

No problem, I am not at the plain old java level yet.
